# Click and drag event handler

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an app with a custom window (transparency and no borders). I made a header with a dragmove behavior on left mouse button down. This allows me to drag the window to the top so it maximizes. Now I want to write the code so that when I click the header and drag it, it restores the windowstate to normal...

Is there a click & drag event handler, or another way?

EDIT: Platform C#, in WPF

Comment: what is your platform? winforms? wpf?  this information REALLY helps us to get you a helpful solution.

Comment: WPF, C#, sorry for not mentioning this at first

Comment: you should edit your question and add that in...also add it as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Window.StateChanged Event

The best way to handle Maximalization and Minimalization is to manipulate WindowState Property. It saves the Window.RestoreBounds property with previous size. If you need more sophisticated solution

[here is an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.restorebounds.aspx)

Ps. Similar to Win 7 feature. Maybe there is no need to do so? :)

Edit: in UIElement there is MoveMove event

```
    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            MainWindow1.WindowState = WindowState.Normal; 
        }
    }
```

this is a bit messy since event is going to fire everytime you move it

Comment: Sorry but that is not what I'm looking for.... I need a handler which does something when I click and drag a ui element....

Comment: DragDrop.GiveFeedback Attached Event
try to be more specific i'm not quiet sure what do you want to do

Comment: I want to restore a maximized window by clicking and dragging a ui element. If user only clicks, nothing should happen, if mousebutton stays down and drags then WindowState == WindowState.Normal;